# Query to find the salary of an employee

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm writing a query in Oracle as follows

```
select rownum as Salary, (rownum + 1) as Increment,(rownum + (rownum + 1)) as Total from dual;
```

And result is as follows

```
Salary   Increment   Total
---------------------------
    1            2        3
```

But i'm trying for to get following result

```
Salary   Increment   Total
---------------------------
    1            2        3
    3            2        5
    5            2        7
```

Here in above result Total of 1st row will become salary in the next row, 
Increment amount will be 2 for an instance, and total of 2nd row will become salary in the 3rd row and so on. help me in getting this result.

Comment: are you using some table. Coz simply joining with dual will always give you one record. Post your actual table and some sample data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will give you that result. Use connect by level to create 3 rows.
Use lag() to retrieve previous total.
I honestly don't know if this is what you are looking for.

```
select nvl(lag(totalAux) over (order by SalaryAux), SalaryAux) as Salary,
       increament,
       totalAux as Total
  from (
  SELECT level        AS SalaryAux,
          2           AS Increament,
        (level * 2)+1 AS TotalAux
  FROM dual
  connect by level <=3);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
    SALARY INCREAMENT      TOTAL
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3
         3          2          5
         5          2          7
```

Comment: Is this logic the same as required *"total of n-1 row will become salary in the n row"*  or is this just producing the same output regardless the logic?

Comment: @Plirkee yes, I'm using `lag(totalAux) over (order by SalaryAux)` to retrieve n-1 Total and place it into Salary. When n=1 `Lag()` will give you `null` so I used `NVL()` to avoid it.

Comment: @Plirkee more on `LAG()` and `LEAD()` analytic functions: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions

Comment: Yes I am familiar with `lag` and `lead` (thanks for the links though). what I was sceptical about was the `total calculation`  .. seems that this will work only for particular numbers. I mean if we have an initial arbitrary `salary`, and arbitrary `increment` for each level - would your approach still work?

Comment: @Plirkee Lag will work in order to retrieve `total`. If `increment` is arbitrary, you are right, calculation of `totalAux` won't work you'll need a table for this. It was kind of an akward requirement anyway, I still don't know what's the OP looking for.